# Customise the help link on standard homepage components?

Tags: home-page-component, customization, help

There is a help link on Homepage components (see screenshot).
[image: Items to Approve Help link highlighted]

I know that you can use the Help settings to redirect this link to a different URL. Is it possible to customise the parameters appended for this particular link:

`?loc=help&target=approvals_processing_approval_requests_parent.htm&section=Dev_Tools`

Or are we stuck with those 3 parameters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me start by saying this. Yes you are stuck with those 3 parameters and I don't think there is a way to add additional parameters to the Standard Help.

But there are ways you can configure the help to be fully custom. Requires some coding and tricks though.

One of things you can do is

1. Build a public Force.com Site with a Visualforce page and define that as your custom Help URL
2. In the Visualforce Page controller, read the page parameters and build redirect methods to redirect to any of your custom built Help pages.
3. You can drive all this through a Custom Settings and make it easy for an Admin to configure it.

Hope this helps.

Also, here is Salesforce Help regarding Custom Help FYR - https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=replacing_online_help.htm&language=en_US&type=0

Comment: Thanks. And extra thanks for the tip of a vf page to redirect. We already have various custom help links on many vf pages so have a system to manage those. This would allow us to integrate with that system!